# Equation of the tangent to the curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the equation of the tangent to the curve:
$F(x) = \sqrt x$ at $x=4$.  (Write answer in slope intercept form)

I am very confused on this and would need step by step directions. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives?  Do you know how to determine which point of $F(x)$ the line will pass through and how to make a line that passes through it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $f(x) = \sqrt x$.

"Step-by-Step Directions" (with "spoilers" so you can check your answers: just hover over the gray with your cursor).

- Find $f'(x)$

  > $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$
- Evaluate $f'(x)$ at $x = 4$. The slope of your line is equal to $m = f'(4)$.

  > $m = \frac 14$
- Then, you have a point on the line (the point at which the desired
  line is tangent. What is $y = f(x) = \sqrt x\;$ when $\;x = 4$?

  > $y = \sqrt 4 = 2$
- Now you have slope, a point on the line $(x_0, y_0) = (4, f(4))$, and
  you can use the point-slope form of an equation: $$y = m(x - x_0) +
     y_0$$ to obtain the equation,

  > $y = \frac 14(x - 4) + 2$
- Finally, manipulate this equation to obtain slope-intercept form.

  > $ y = \frac 14 x + 1$

Comment: Excellent use of spoilers! :-) Sorry, I peeked in each one! +1

Comment: I've taken your lead, @Amzoti! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$$F(x) = \sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$$
$$F'(x) = (1/2)*x^{1/2-1} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = 1/4$$
$$T(x) = F'(x_o)*(x-x_o)+F(x_o)$$

where $x_o$ is the x value where you take the tangent (4)

$$T(x) = x/4+1$$